# How can I locate middle character of a word in a text file?

Tags: c, file

How can I locate middle character of a first word in a text file and later use it to count other occurrences of that character? I have function which counts words in a text file and function which count length of first word.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define maxBuf 128

void howMany(FILE * file);
void words(FILE * file);

int main() {
FILE *temp, *file;
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
temp = fopen("temp.txt","w");
char sd1[maxBuf];

howMany(file);
words(file);

fclose(file);
fclose(temp);

unlink("test.txt");
rename("temp.txt","test.txt");

return 0;  
}
void howMany(FILE * file){
char sd1[maxBuf];
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
int i, z, c;
char word[1000];

while (!feof(file)) {
        if(fscanf(file,"%s",word)==1);
        printf("word read is: %s\n", word);
        printf("word read is: %i\n", strlen(word));                  
        break;
}
}
void words(FILE * file){
file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
char sd1[maxBuf];
int iwant; 
int nwords = 0; 

char word[1000];
int i, z;

while (fscanf(file, "%s", sd1) == 1) {

++nwords;
}
printf("There are %i words. \n", nwords);
}
```

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Random access into the file? Getting the file size? This question is very vague.

Comment: @JanDvorak at finding middle character of a word.

Comment: middle character of a word != middle character of a text file

Comment: Show us what you have tried, or considered

Comment: The former is easy: just read in the string, compute its length, divide by two, index into the string. You should define what happens if the string length is even.

Comment: The latter is just as easy, but uses a different API.

Comment: This smells with homework. You should be able to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Indent your code.

Check the result of functions like `fopen, fgets` ...

`MAX_BUF` is a better name for `maxBuf`

```
size_t middle, n = strlen(sd1);
middle = (n / 2) + (n % 2 != 0);
```